# Is it possible to have one Unicorn child process a queue, whilst the rest process web requests on Heroku single Dyno?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, resque, unicorn

If you have Unicorn set up on a single dyno on Heroku, say with 3 workers. 
Is it possible to have 2 of the child workers processing web requests, and 1 Unicorn child doing background jobs, such as a resque queue, or scheduled tasks?

Or is that just not appropriate?

---

Now got it Working!

OK, so using the answer bellow I managed to get it to pick up the cue, but it took a bit of tinkering first. This is what worked for me.

Procfile

```
web: bundle exec unicorn_rails -p $PORT -c config/unicorn.rb
```

unicorn.rb

```
worker_processes 2
preload_app true
timeout 30

@resque_pid = nil

before_fork do |server, worker|
  @resque_pid ||= spawn("bundle exec rake environment resque:work QUEUE=*")
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly is possible - take a read of http://bugsplat.info/2011-11-27-concurrency-on-heroku-cedar.html. I've not tried it myself though but I will be soon. Essentially, you'll end up with a unicorn.rb that looks like

```
worker_processes 3
timeout 30

@resque_pid = nil

before_fork do |server, worker|
  @resque_pid ||= spawn("bundle exec rake " + \
  "resque:work QUEUES=scrape,geocode,distance,mailer")
end
```

I'm not entirely sure of the 'appropriateness' since it means Heroku is essentially loosing out on revenue but they haven't taken any stops to block this behaviour (nor I think would they).

Comment: Yea, I was working through the bugsplat tutorial last night, but could  not get it to pick up the queue...

Comment: As for appropriate, I just wasn't sure if each forked process would have to be alike for each unicorn master. I don't think heroku have any objection to unicorn, they reference it several times in their documentation. It's only 1 Dyno running at capacity after all. They're more likely to object to deliberate cloning of apps with shared DB to circumvent their policy, as you could end up with several dynos being tied up for 1 free app.

Comment: also apparently a dyno can spawn up to 15 threads - but you need to be careful of memory usage.

Comment: I would be /very/ wary of this as essentially you're then binding your web scale to your worker scale.  You're going to end up with a surplus somewhere.

http://www.12factor.net/concurrency

Comment: If you use the zero-down time deploys that github do for Unicorn (USR2 and QUIT the old master) this will end up creating a new worker process for each time you reload/USR2 the master.

Comment: This is really just for testing and development. I would never use this for a production set up that may need to scale to more than one dyno.